# Starting a windows 10 app full screen mode

Tags: windows

I have several pc terminals at work that generally will just run a windows 10 store app on them they will be powered down for the weekends and autostart sunday pm.

I have attempted to try to make the app start in full screen, by dragging a shortcut from the start menu to

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

I then set the run field in the shortcut tab of the shortcuts properties to maximised. But still the app starts at a default size.

I know that I can set windows to tablet mode but I would rather leave it as is.

Ideally I would prefer fullscreen mode to maximised i.e no taskbar / window.

Is there something easy that I am missing? - maybe a way for the app remember how the last sessions was left on close as any generic windows program would by default.